# IQueryable async loop

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

Here is a linq to sql query:

```
var query = db.Table1.Where(t => t.age >= 18); 
foreach (var item in query)
{
   ...
}

var query2 = query.Where(t => t.dept == 1234);
foreach (var item in query2)
{
     ...
}
```

query and query2 are IQueryable objects. That means the sql queries are not executed until the foreach loop.

The previous code works fine. But i want to know how i can make this code async.

Here is what i've tried:

```
var query = db.Table1.Where(t => t.age >= 18); 
var res1 = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in res1)
{
   ...
}

var query2 = query.Where(t => t.dept = 1234);
var res2 = await query2.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in res2)
{
     ...
}
```

It works, but it is ugly to my eyes because i have to add 2 lines in my code.

So my question is: Is there a way to make the loop async ?

Something like that:

```
await foreach (var item in query2.ToListAsync())
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `var query = await query.Where(t => t.dept = 1234).ToListAsync();`

its important to understand the little differences but you could have it in 1 line like... the above

Comment: `.Where(t => t.dept = 1234);` **the assignment operator** is a typo, right?

Comment: `foreach (var item in query2)` should probably be `foreach (var item in res2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `await` keyword inside the `foreach` statement like so:

```
foreach (var item in await query2.ToListAsync())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is no different to the existing code - Not sure how this will run the query in the background without blocking

Answer (score 0):

You should not await the calls to `ToListAsync()` Directly. fire off the all your queries and then await the results.

##### UPDATE - Missed the subtlety of the chained where for query2

```
// base query
var query = db.Table1.Where(t => t.age >= 18);

// execute the base query but do not await the result.
var res1 = query.ToListAsync();

// execute a second query adding an additional filter but do not await the result
var res2 = query.Where(t => t.dept == 1234).ToListAsync();

// process the results of the base query.
foreach (var item in await res1)
{
   ...
}

// process the results of the second query.
foreach (var item in await res2)
{
     ...
}
```

There are a couple of mistakes in your code too **(Now fixed in the question)**

- `query.Where(t => t.dept = 1234);` should probably be `query.Where(t => t.dept == 1234);` - Note double equals for equality check rather than a single one for assignment (I'd bet this is a typo though)
- `foreach (var item in query2)` should probably be `foreach (var item in res2)` - there's not much point calling `ToListAsync()` and ignoring the result.

Comment: OPs code also has an assignment in the `Where` of `query2`, which I doubt compiles.

Comment: @Fildor Another good spot.

Comment: sorry i've edit my mistakes